# Is it possible to identify the user from a access token in rest server

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, authorization, spring-restcontroller

I am new in rest services and Oauth. I have followed the example below. How can I allow user "A" only update his own user profile but not allow to updating user "B"?

https://jaxenter.com/rest-api-spring-java-8-112289.html

Thank you
Wing